# Trouble setting up igraph with C++

Tags: igraph

So, I'm pretty new to using packages in C++. I downloaded igraph from http://igraph.org/c/ and installed it successfully. But when I try to #include  I get the error "fatal error: 'igraph.h' file not found". Where do I need to put the directory containing all the igraph files in order to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the C compiler you use, there should be a setting for the "include path" of the compiler - this setting tells the compiler where to look for files to be `#include`d. Check these directories for a file named `igraph.h` - if none of the directories contain `igraph.h`, you should either adjust the include path or the name of the file being included.

A common mistake for igraph users on Linux is that the igraph include files are installed in `/usr/include/igraph`. Since `/usr/include` is usually on the default include path of the C compiler but `/usr/include/igraph` isn't, you have to use `#include <igraph/igraph.h>` in your file instead of `#include <igraph.h>`.

Comment: Im new to C/C++ development, took me like two days to find this answer. How are you meant to know to put igraph/igraph.h versus just igraph.h?

Comment: Well, first you look around in the include paths of your compiler and then realize that the header is in `/usr/include/igraph/igraph.h` and not in `/usr/include/igraph.h`. Next, you realize that `/usr/include` is in the include path of your compiler so you need to specify a path relative to that.

But note that this answer is from 2014, and it's 2022 now, so you can simply read igraph's tutorial at https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Tutorial.html#tut-lesson-1 -- note that the tutorial uses `igraph.h`, but it also describes that you need to set the include path of your compiler appropriately.